# How do I create toggle buttons with rounded edges on the outsides and slanted edges on the insides?

Tags: css, transform, pseudo-element

I am okay with the JavaScript part of creating this toggle, but the CSS part is giving me a headache, especially dealing with the borders.

I would like to know the best way to code this element: [Element Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjQgD.png)

Comment: Please provide a code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a combination of border-radius, transform: skewX and pseduo elements you should be able to achieve this result. Feel free to tinker with the padding, height value, etc.

https://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/ZyvqKz

```
<button class="btn btn-left">Button</button><button class="btn btn-right">Button</button>

.btn {
  height:40px;
  padding:10px 40px;
  border:0;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
}
.btn-left {
  border-radius:20px 0 0 20px;
  background:yellow;
}
.btn-left:after {
  content:'';
  width:20px;
  margin-left:-10px;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  background:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  z-index:1;
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
}
.btn-right {
  border-radius:0 20px 20px 0;
  background:white;
  margin-left:20px;
  border:2px solid #eee;
}
.btn-right:before {
  content:'';
  width:20px;
  margin-left:-11px;
  top:-2px;
  height:100%;
  background:white;
  display:inline-block;
  z-index:1;
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  border-top:2px solid #eee;
  border-bottom:2px solid #eee;
  border-left:2px solid #eee;
}
```